# mysql probem on Leetcode

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a question from LEETCODE.I don't know why my output is wrong. First I write the SELECT in the parenthesis to find out the repeated email address. Then I use the DELETE to filter out the repeated email address so anyone know what is wrong  with my code? [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmnnE.png)[mycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1gEh.png)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRXNE.png)

Comment: which version of mysql you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

it is very simple. try this

-- Solution 1

```
with cte as
(
    select id, email, Rank() OVER (partition by email order by id) ranks
    from person where email in(
        select email from person
        group by email having count(email) >1
    )
)
DELETE FROM person where id in
(
    SELECT id FROM CTE where ranks!=1
)
```

-- Solution 2

```
DELETE p from person p 
inner join (
    select MIN(id) id, email from person 
    where email in(
        select email from person group by email having count(email)>1
        ) group by email
) A On P.Id>A.id and p.email = a.email;
```

Comment: Solution 2 is easy to understand Thanks

Comment: please accept and upvote if this has solved problem.